# Calculate time difference between each records for first call resolution

Tags: reporting-services, calculation

I need to calculate the time difference for repeated calls via SSRS.

I have tried adding count of rows but I am currently stuck in there as I need to count get the difference between when a repeated call was made.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you need is difference between ANI field per row value.

I took example of one of my sample data.

If you can see I took Status to check if previous and current value are same or different.

I created 2 new column for your simplicity.

Previous which will show only previous value of status and then Count different status which will do the counting as below.

If they are same then I just put it as simple 0 and if they are different then I put as 1

[image]

How did I do that
[image]

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!status.Value)=Fields!status.Value,CInt(0),CInt(1))
```

Previous status coulmn as

```
=Previous(Fields!status.Value)
```

Note you now know how to get difference, you can use your imagination what you wish to achieve.

Comment: this is easy as we have distinguishing columns for the updated value, but my data doesn't have such and only thing that I can use as a basis is the ANI field. Say first row and second row is the same, get difference between time stamps.

Comment: If I understand your comment, your reference column to check difference is ANI, This is similar to my status column.
You mentioned difference between 2 time stamps, In my example I showed you 1 and 0 but you can change 1 with Date difference function of your timestamp. It should give you your desired result.